# How to get the name property of the active NamedSheetView class?

Tags: excel, vba, office365, class-properties

Excel now has the possibility to store personal filtering views to help collaboration in simultaniously used documents.
I could only find Microsoft documentation for an add-in, but the function is available in my Excel version of MS Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13127.20266) 32bit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.namedsheetview?view=excel-js-preview

I am trying to store the currently applied NamedSheetView name property (for later restoring option) but
this code fails:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim xViewName As String
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet6.Name)
xViewName = sh1.NamedSheetView.Name
```

However this code works (with previously created "Test" view):

```
sh1.NamedSheetViews.GetItem("Test").Activate
```

If this NamedSheetViews is a collection, I should be able to get the item property, but these codes also fail:

```
strName = sh1.NamedSheetViews.GetItem(1).Name
strName = sh1.NamedSheetViews.Item(1).Name
```

Anyone has ever succeeded in getting the current NamedSheetView of a Worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
(Thanks for the great help from TinMan)

```
Dim SheetView As NamedSheetView 
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim ActiveSheetView as string 
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet6.Name) 
Set SheetView = sh1.NamedSheetViews.GetActive
ActiveSheetView = SheetView.Name
```

Application:

```
sh1.NamedSheetViews.GetItem(ActiveSheetView).Activate
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I probe unknown Object properties:

[image: Testing Method]

I start with a reference to the Object.  If I don't know what the Object is I use `TypeName()` to return it's class name (data type).  I then declare a variable of that data type.  Wash, rinse and repeat as I drill down the structure.  Once the variable is declared, selecting the variable and pressing F1 with open the Microsoft Help document for that data type.

### Module Code

```
Sub WhatIsThat()
    Const TestName As String = "TestName"
    Dim View As NamedSheetViewCollection
    Set View = Sheet6.NamedSheetViews
    
    On Error Resume Next
    View.GetItem(TestName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    View.Add TestName
    Dim SheetView As NamedSheetView
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To View.Count - 1
        Debug.Print View.GetItemAt(n).Name
        Set SheetView = View.GetItemAt(n)
        Debug.Print SheetView.Name
    Next
    Stop
End Sub
```

### Immediate Window Tests

```
?TypeName(Sheet6.NamedSheetViews)
?View.GetItemAt(0).Name
?TypeName( View.GetItemAt(0))
```

Comment: Thank you TinMan, this was a great help. Now I am able to iterate through the collection. I am still faced with the big question: how can I identify the active NamedSheetView - the one currently active on the sheet - if any. Unfortunately the NamedSheetView - just as the collection - only has Parent, Count, Name and Application properties. Unfortunately I could not find any trace of what NamedSheetView is curretly applied among the Sheet properties either. Any advice how to identify the currently selected NamedSheetView?

Comment: I was only able to find Javascript API code: GetActive() 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.namedsheetviewcollection?view=excel-js-preview

Comment: FOUND IT!
Dim SheetView As NamedSheetView
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet6.Name)
Set SheetView = sh1.NamedSheetViews.GetActive

Comment: @LegrA Way to go!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I record a Macro With the views I have in my workbook and it works and came out to simpler than I thought so.
It is as follows:

```
 Sub ViewPractice()
'
' ViewPractice Macro
'
ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews("Setup").Show
ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews("DashBoard").Show
End Sub
```